# How much mass should be removed from balloon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

If a hot air balloon has a mass of 310 kg and it is motionless due to an upward buoyant force, how much weight should be removed to obtain an acceleration of 0.15m/s^2 upward. I am not sure how to create an equation using these variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are two forces acting on the balloon, the weight and the buoyant force. Note that they have opposite directions.

You're given the information that the net force acting on it is zero (motionless) when its mass is 310 kg. How much weight is it equivalent to? What does this tell you about the magnitude of the buoyant force?

Now that you know the buoyant force (which points upward), how much weight do you have to remove so that the acceleration due to the net force acting on the balloon is worth 0.15 m/s^2 upward?